# How can I suppress TortoiseHg "new branch in remote repository" warning?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I use TortoiseHg as my version control solution. Because I put every feature on a separate branch, I often create new branches. Each time I want to push a new branch, I am presented with a warning about creating a new branch in the remote repository:

[image: TortoiseHg warning about creating a new branch in the remote repository]

I am somewhat annoyed by this, because I can't think of a reason not to create a branch in the remote repository when I am pushing changesets on this branch. Is there any way I can tell TortoiseHg to always push new branches to the remote repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Synchronization view (<kbd>ALT-4</kbd>), click the Options button and select "Allow push of a new branch":

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find this because I never use the synchronization view and didn't realise there is a dedicated options button there.

Comment: Is there a way of setting this for all repos, rather than have to individually do all 70 of my registered ones?

Comment: @freefaller I tested the setting and it applied to all repos.  On Windows it is stored in AppData\Roaming\TortoiseHg\TortoiseHgQt.ini and not in Mercurial.ini (global settings) or .hg\hgrc (repo settings).

Comment: @MarkTolonen - Hmmm, I'm not see that... if I click options for one repo, it's only saving the tick for that one repo (plus the dialog title states the name of the repo itself).  I can't see an obvious setting in the TortoiseHgQt.ini file either

Comment: @freefaller Are you using the latest version?  I have 4.5.3.  The settings was under `[sync]` section, `new-branch=true`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen - ah, no, it appears I'm a little behind (4.3.1). Have upgraded and tick is now global. Many thanks for your time, and apologies for wasting it!